# angular lazy loading service worker prefetch

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, service-worker

I realized that using lazy loading loses the major

feature of a pwa if the user does not visit the page

you do not have the possibility of offline browsing.

So is there a way to prefetch the lazy loading files ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need to define the pre-loading strategy:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})]
```

See http://recurship.com/blog/2017/9/30/introduction-to-angular-router-lazy-loading-and-prefetchin for more details

Also see https://blog.cloudboost.io/angular-faster-performance-and-better-user-experience-with-lazy-loading-a4f323b2cf4a

CUSTOM PRELOADING STRATEGY:

You can also preload some and not others with a custom preload strategy.

See https://blog.cloudboost.io/angular-faster-performance-and-better-user-experience-with-lazy-loading-a4f323b2cf4a#e836

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadingStrategy, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class CustomPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
  preloadedModules: string[] = [];

  preload(route: Route, load: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    if (route.data && route.data['preload']) { // see app.routing.ts
      this.preloadedModules.push(route.path);
      return load();
    } else {
      return Observable.of(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: 
CustomPreloadingStrategy })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [CustomPreloadingStrategy]
})
```

app.routing.ts:

```
{
    path: ':section',
    loadChildren: './gm-email/gm-email.module#GmEmailModule',
    data: { preload: true }
}
```

Basically, if data.preload is true you are saying preload this one immediately AFTER the app has loaded (i.e. AFTER the first module has lazy loaded) ELSE preload it on demand (i.e. when the user clicks a link lazy load it)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but with PreloadAllModules you lose the benefit of lazyloading or am I wrong?

Comment: I have never tried but I think it starts preloading AFTER it has lazy loaded the initial module, otherwise there is no point preloading - also, you can define custom preloading strategies

Comment: For this scenario, Angular provides a method to tell the router to load all the lazy loading modules asynchronously immediately AFTER the app loads and not to wait for the module to get activated when the user clicks.

Comment: I know you can set up a custom loader but Ive never see about , "Angular provides a method to tell the router to load all the lazy loading modules  ...." can you give me a hint or some links, please ?

Comment: edited my answer to cover custom preloading ... BTW "Angular provides a method to tell the router to load ALL the lazy loading modules" is talking about PreloadAllModules

Comment: thanks for the exhaustive :) answer but I just know of custom preloader I've the same code in my app.1) "router to load all the lazy loading modules asynchronously immediately AFTER the app loads"  
Are you sure about this ? I never seen it. 2) and other problem is that I've all my app lazy loading so in app.routing I've only the main routes (my features home auth admin) with forRoot and than in each module an other lazyloadin of the 'partials' ie for the admin posts media users with forChild so I dont really know if still using PreloadAllModules the child module are loading

Comment: If you click through to a module it should load quicker. Also there shouldn't be any requests for resources other than HTTP API requests in the network tab. Obviously, this assumes that the preloading has finished when you click around in your app.

Comment: you may also want to compare this to what happens when you do not prefetch - keep an eye on the browser console network tab

Answer (score 1):

In the Angular service worker file ngsw-config.json, setting `installMode` to `prefetch` and specifying `/*.js` in the `resources.files` array will instruct the Angular service worker to prefetch your lazy loading .js bundles when the PWA is installed without losing the benefit of lazy loading if your user is navigating online in a browser.

Example:

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```